# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed Laravel routing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I launch command: `php artisan route:cache` I get message:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

There is only one closure in routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

})
```

I use php 7.1

Comment: `routes/api.php` has a closure route.

Comment: I commented this route: `/*Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');*/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the closure in `routes/api.php` to controller or comment it

```php
// Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//    return $request->user();
// });
```

Then run

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Laravel will try to cache routes by serializing to base64 encoded text in `bootstrap/cache/routes.php`, and closures can't be serialized

Comment: But what is initial reason of that? Could I fix without moving to controller?

Comment: Laravel will try to cache routes by serializing to base64 encoded text, and closures can't be serialized

Comment: Why? Should I activate PHP extension?

Comment: Maybe turn off cache? or change php version?

Comment: @OPV None of those ideas make sense or will work. If you're not using that one example route, just remove it.